# How to blur specefic area on the ubuntu desktop

Tags: gnome, programming

I am a CS student and want to work on my FYP project that will get the pixels from the desktop screen and will blur the intended pixel on the screen at run time. For example, if I want to blur the specific images then It should blur it at run time on the ubuntu desktop screen. I know how to blur something from images or from a webcam using a machine learning model. But in this case, I want to blur the specific area(which will be trained using the ML model) and will work on the desktop screen. Hope you get what I am trying to say.

As I searched a lot, I found only the object detection in the case of video or webcam. But I want to work it like my idea (i.e on desktop screen it should detect objects.). Will be very thankful If someone can help.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 
Gnome Shell 3.36.8

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu? You do not mention any supported version of Ubuntu or any supported program.

Comment: What do you mean by supported version? Ubuntu uses Gnome for UI and I want to do something with that to control pixels of the Desktop.

Comment: @MuhammadAamirKhan David is slightly correct! You must tell which version of Ubuntu you are using. Different versions of Ubuntu use different versions of Gnome Shell. For eg:- Ubuntu 21.10 _impish_ uses Gnome 4.0 whereas Ubuntu 20.04 _focal_ uses Gnome 3.6. Every version of Gnome Shell has different source files and modifications. Without your release and Gnome Shell version, it's almost impossible to answer your question. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: sir, I am using gnome version 3.36.8 and my ubuntu version is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Is there any way to get and blur the pixels from the Gnome.

Comment: at this initial stage, I want to blur the pixels on the Ubuntu Desktop. Later I will do some more modification.